# Shopify - Variant quantity in my cart liquid cart.js

Tags: javascript, php, shopify, cart

I've been spending hours to try to figure it out + forum, so next step is to post my problem! :)

So what I want to do is to display a message to my user in my cart.js. They are allowed to order when the product is "out of stock" but I want to display a message on my cart.js saying 2/3 weeks delivery.

I tried to add that in my cart.liquid :

```js
bkseen
```

```html
<p class="cart-item__variant"> {{ line_item.variant.inventory_quantity }}</p>
                
{% assign lineItemVariant = line_item.variant %}
  {% if lineItemVariant.inventory_management == "shopify" %}
    <span class="delivery-message">
      {% if lineItemVariant.inventory_quantity > 0 %}
        Quick delivery
      {% else %}
        2-3 weeks delivery
      {% endif %}
    </span>
  {% endif %}
```

I've tested the code above and the result is pretty weird.

If I put the quantity in my table between `<td></td>`, that automatically format every values as the last one. I guess it's because of Rivet.js mixing data on the back.

And if I put the code out of `<td>` tags it works perfectly.. the thing is, I want to display it for each line, that's the point !

Check the result by a screenshot :

[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COzLK.jpg)

If you have any question do not hesistate.

Cheers

bkseen

Comment: Is 2-3 weeks per item or per order?

Comment: And it's probably in the wrong place. Try placing the code inside `<ul class="cart-items plain">....</ul>` appropriately.